# How to avoid EN_CHANGE notifications when sending WM_SETTEXT?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-controls, mfc

I have a CEdit derived control that displays the string "N/A" when the undelying data is null. I recently added code to empty the control(SetWindowText("");) when it gains focus and set if back to "N/A"(SetWindowText("N/A"))  when the focus is lost if the user left the control empty.

The only problem is that setting the window text to "" or "N/A" triggers EN_CHANGE, so my dialog thinks that the data has changed.

How can I avoid EN_CHANGE from being fired when calling SetWindowText (WM_SETTEXT)?

NOTES

-I know I can set the edit control to Multiline=TRUE but that's not accpectable for me.

-My application is MBCS so I can't use SetCueBanner

-I want an elegant solution. Setting the parent window to NULL temporarily is not an elegant solution.

EDIT:

-I want the solution to be in my custom control, not in each dialog

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a suitable solution to my problem.

First, I added a flag to my derived control's header file and I initialized it to false in the constructor

```
bool m_bNoEnChange;
```

---

I overrode the OnChildNotify in my derived control's header file and in the implementation, I checked for the WM_COMMAND message with the EN_CHANGE parameter. I then returned TRUE to prevent the message from being sent to the parent(dialog/page)

```
virtual BOOL OnChildNotify(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pLResult);
```

---

```
BOOL CADEdit::OnChildNotify(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pLResult) 
{
    if(message == WM_COMMAND && HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE)
    {
        //If the flag is set, don't send the message to the parent window
        if(m_bNoEnChange)
            return TRUE;
    }

    return CEdit::OnChildNotify(message, wParam, lParam, pLResult);
}
```

---

Finally, when the control gains and loses focus, I wrapped the problematic SetWindowText with my flag

```
m_bNoEnChange = true;
SetWindowText(_T(""));
m_bNoEnChange = false;
```

---

This solution is the best in my case because I don't have to modify each dialog.

Comment: use UpdateData, and you won't receive a message again.

Comment: UpdateData is a dialog level function, not an CEdit function.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the problem. My problem came from code called inside the CEdit control. I can't call UpdateData from there. Have a look at the UpdateData documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9fb9hww(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: In addition, UpdateData retreives the data from the dialog and transfers it to the variables. In my case, I don't want the data to be transfered.

Answer (score 10):

The way I've done it before (last time, like 20 minutes ago; in fact I was thinking about asking the same question), is by setting a flag. When I'm about to set the text programatically, I set the flag, and I check it in the EN_CHANGE handler:

```
void CMyDialog::MyFunction()
{    
    setEditTextProgramatically = true;  
    c_Edit.SetWindowText(_T("Whatever"));  
    setEditTextProgramatically = false;
}

void CMyDialog::OnEnChangeEdit()
{
    if (!setEditTextProgramatically)
    {
        // Do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

I know it's not the most elegant solution, but it works, at least for me.

I've always wondered why MFC doesn't provide a way to distinguish user input from changes from code, but that's the way it is.

Comment: I have similar solutions for working around MFC notifications. It gets really fun when you have notifications calling notifications, recursively.

Comment: It's not really MFC that is involved in sending the message.  It's the underlying Win32 "EDIT" control that sends the message. The CEdit is just a wrapper around it.

Comment: @VanDarg Yes, things get interesting when notifications call notifications. In such scenarios, it can be difficult to control if it was user input or the code that caused the notification. But for simple cases, this solution can work.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson True, it's Win32 who sends the message. But maybe, if MFC were a "thicker" wrapper, they could have added some more information. Anyway, I often wish that kind of information were available, no matter who provided it.

Comment: +1, but I must do this in my custom control, not in each of my 200 dialogs

Comment: That waste of 3 hours pulling my hair out trying to figure out why its not working. Finally, all made sense now. Thanks.

Comment: See also [Avoiding EN_CHANGE notifications](http://www.flounder.com/avoid_en_change.htm) by Joseph Newcomer, 2006.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable `(EnableWindow(FALSE)` or send `WM_ENABLE` with param FALSE) the control prior to sending `WM_SETTEXT` then enabling it afterwards. That should prevent the `EN_CHANGE`

There is probably some more elegant method :p

Comment: Disabling edit control didn't prevent EN_CHANGE for me... using Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

The below code uses a C++ 11 feature, but that can easily be changed.

HEADER

```
// CEditOptionalNotify.h
//
// CEdit derived class allowing the control's text value to be
// set without (optionally) causing EN_CHANGE processing.
//
#pragma once

class CEditOptionalNotify : public CEdit
{
    //DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CEditOptionalNotify)
    // Enable use of RUNTIME_CLASS macro and CObject::IsKindOf()

public:

    CEditOptionalNotify();
    virtual ~CEditOptionalNotify();

    enum class PerformOnChangeProcessing { No, Yes };
    void vSetText(const TCHAR* pText, PerformOnChangeProcessing e);

protected:

    afx_msg BOOL bConsiderEnChangeAsHandled();

    bool m_bChangeNotificationsEnabled;

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

IMPLEMENTATION

```
// EditOptionalNotify.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <EditOptionalNotify.h>

//IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CEditOptionalNotify, CEdit)

CEditOptionalNotify::CEditOptionalNotify() :
    m_bChangeNotificationsEnabled(true)
{ 
}

CEditOptionalNotify::~CEditOptionalNotify()
{
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEditOptionalNotify, CEdit)
    ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX(EN_CHANGE, bConsiderEnChangeAsHandled)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


BOOL CEditOptionalNotify::bConsiderEnChangeAsHandled()
{
    return (m_bChangeNotificationsEnabled ? FALSE : TRUE);
}


void CEditOptionalNotify::vSetText(const TCHAR* pText, PerformOnChangeProcessing e)
{
    bool bChangeNotificationsDesired = (PerformOnChangeProcessing::No == e ? false : true);

    if (bChangeNotificationsDesired != m_bChangeNotificationsEnabled)
    {
        m_bChangeNotificationsEnabled = bChangeNotificationsDesired;
        CEdit::SetWindowText(pText);
        m_bChangeNotificationsEnabled = (bChangeNotificationsDesired ? false : true);
    }
    else
        CEdit::SetWindowText(pText);
}
```

Comment: I like the ON_CONTROL_REFLECT part of your code, which seems less cumbersome than the OnChildNotify part of mine. 
Something's botherrng me, will your control work if the vSetText method is not used? (like in DoDataExchange, in SetWindowText)

Answer (score 0):

```
LRESULT CMainDlg::OnEnUpdateEditID(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{   
    //using static variable
    static bool isCodeChangeText = false;
    if(isCodeChangeText) 
        return 0;

    ……//Deal Window Text

    if(old == new)
        return 0; 

    int nSel = m_editPID.GetSel();//record cursor pos

    isCodeChangeText = true;
    m_editID.SetWindowText(new);
    m_editID.SetSel(nSel);
    isCodeChangeText = false;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case somebody else finds this discussion...

As Steven wrote UpdateData does not cause an EN_CHANGE being sent.

Under the hood MFC calls AfxSetWindowText with which one can specify one hwnd.